# SELECT INTO Variable in MySQL DECLARE causes syntax error?

Tags: mysql, select, mysql-workbench, declare

I´d like to SELECT a single value into a variable. I´d tried to following:

```
DECLARE myvar INT(4);
```

-- immediately returns some syntax error.

```
SELECT myvalue 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE anothervalue = 1;
```

-- returns a single integer

```
SELECT myvalue 
  INTO myvar 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE anothervalue = 1;
```

-- does not work, also tried @myvar

Is possible to use DECLARE outside of stored procedures or functions?

Maybe I just dont get the concept of user variables... I just tried:

```
SELECT myvalue INTO @var FROM `mytable` WHERE uid = 1;
SELECT @var;
```

...which worked just like it´s supposed to. But if I run each query at a time i just get @var NULL.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In the end a stored procedure was the solution for my problem.

Here´s what helped:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
BEGIN
  DECLARE myvar DOUBLE;
  SELECT somevalue INTO myvar FROM mytable WHERE uid = 1;

  SELECT myvar;
END//

DELIMITER ;

call test();
```

Comment: Thx for the testing... sounds interesting. Unfortunately I do not get the last sentence. Did you forget a word or two?

Answer (score 129):

I ran into this same issue, but I think I know what's causing the confusion. If you use MySQL Query Analyzer, you can do this just fine:

```
SELECT myvalue 
INTO @myvar 
FROM mytable 
WHERE anothervalue = 1;
```

However, if you put that same query in MySQL Workbench, it will throw a syntax error. I don't know why they would be different, but they are.

To work around the problem in MySQL Workbench, you can rewrite the query like this:

```
SELECT @myvar:=myvalue
FROM mytable
WHERE anothervalue = 1;
```

Comment: Indeed that is interesting. Added a MySQL workbench tag to the question – so others might find that this issue is related to MySQL Workbench.

Comment: I used MySQL workbench version 5.2.47 rev 10398 on Fedora 18 and there is not such problem with it.

Comment: the second solution `:=` will be deprecated. So prefer to use the `SELECT ... INTO` !

Answer (score 51):

These answers don't cover very well MULTIPLE variables.

Doing the inline assignment in a stored procedure causes those results to ALSO be sent back in the resultset. That can be confusing. To using the SELECT...INTO syntax with multiple variables you do:

```
SELECT a, b INTO @a, @b FROM mytable LIMIT 1;
```

The SELECT must return only 1 row, hence LIMIT 1, although that isn't always necessary.

Comment: I was trying to do the same, variables without @ also worked for me. Thanks

Comment: yes, in a stored procedure variables don't have to start with @. But, it is easier to demonstrate that way.

Answer (score 29):

You can also use SET instead of DECLARE

```
SET @myvar := (SELECT somevalue INTO myvar FROM mytable WHERE uid=1);

SELECT myvar;
```

Comment: This works and has clean syntax which I like

Comment: it must be SELECT @myvar

Answer (score 15):

Per [the MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare.html) DECLARE works only at the start of a BEGIN...END block as in a stored program.

Comment: After googling for 'mysql select inside procedure' and arrived here, not having the declarations at the beginning is what was causing the `syntax error, missing ;` error for me.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to DECLARE a variable in MySQL.  A variable's type is determined automatically when it is first assigned a value.  Its type can be one of: integer, decimal, floating-point, binary or nonbinary string, or NULL value.  See the User-Defined Variables documentation for more information:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

You can use SELECT ... INTO to assign columns to a variable:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into-statement.html

Example:

```
mysql> SELECT 1 INTO @var;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @var;
+------+
| @var |
+------+
| 1    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Hmm, somehow I am in trouble here.. 
SELECT 1 INTO @var; 
returns a syntax error too. so does:
SELECT somevar INTO @var FROM mytable;

Maybe it´s a DELIMITER problem?

Comment: What error are you receiving? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTO @var' at line 3.     Version=5.5.16

Answer (score 5):

I am using version 6 (MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.0.9  revision 11421 build 1170) on Windows Vista. I have no problem with the following options. Probably they fixed it since these guys got the problems three years ago.

```
/* first option */
SELECT ID 
INTO @myvar 
FROM party 
WHERE Type = 'individual';

-- get the result
select @myvar;

/* second option */
SELECT @myvar:=ID
FROM party
WHERE Type = 'individual';


/* third option. The same as SQL Server does */
SELECT @myvar = ID FROM party WHERE Type = 'individual';
```

All option above give me a correct result.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that despite the fact that you can `SELECT INTO` global variables like:

`SELECT ... INTO @XYZ ...`

You can **NOT** use `FETCH INTO` global variables like:

`FETCH ... INTO @XYZ`

Looks like it's not a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=2261). I hope it will be helpful to someone...

Answer (score 4):

For those running in such issues right now, just try to put an alias for the table, this should the trick, e.g:

```
SELECT myvalue 
  INTO myvar 
  FROM mytable x
 WHERE x.anothervalue = 1;
```

It worked for me.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe miss the @ symbol before your value,like that `select 'test' INTO @myValue`;

Comment: That's a session variable, different topic

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
    c1, c2, c3, ...
INTO 
    @v1, @v2, @v3,...
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    condition;