# Informix stored procedure errors

Tags: sql, informix

I am trying to create a simple procedure that looks for a fname and lname when given a number

```
create procedure _lookup_name (_no int)
select (fname || ' ' || lname)  from table where number = _no;
end procedure;
```

I keep getting an error saying that "INTO TEMP table required for SELECT statement.

Comment: How do you want the procedure to return the value?

Comment: I had a bunch of other syntax in there that defined a variable and then told the select statement to put the result into that variable but I still got a syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the results of the `select` statement into a variable or table. See:
[w3schools (into table)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) or [here temp table in memory](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-table-variables)

Comment: is there a way to do it without making a temp table?

Comment: You may be able to. Someone else may know better. You may be able to make an object that has some sort of array of the values from your select statement. But it'd probably be easier to just make it a temp table in memory or something.

Comment: Try looking at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error)

Comment: I tried this and the same result      create procedure _lookup_name (_no int)
begin
declare name varchar(100);
select (fname || ' ' || lname) into name from table where no = _no;
select name;
end;

Comment: This is because your select statement can return more than one name, and your name variable cannot hold more than one name. I recommend a temp table...

Answer (score 0):

maybe :

```
define var1 char(30);
define var2 char(30);
create procedure _lookup_name (_no int)
    select (fname || ' ' || lname) into var1,var2 from table where number = _no;
end procedure;
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation what this fixes and why?