# MySQL Select into variable

Tags: mysql, execute, prepare

I want to further use in the procedure the values I get from a select into execution but can't figure out how to do it.

As a test I wrote the following but cannot use the v_1, v_2 or v_3 variables for further logic as they don't take the values 1,2 & 3 as i expected...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MPT_testing; DELIMITER //  CREATE PROCEDURE MPT_testing() READS SQL DATA BEGIN

  DECLARE v_1 INT;   DECLARE v_2 INT;   DECLARE v_3 INT;
     SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT 1,2 into v_1, v_2');   PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;   EXECUTE s1;   DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;

  SET v_3 = v_1 + v_2;

  SELECT v_3;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Can somebody help here please?

thanks,
Leo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing 'SELECT 1,2 into v_1, v_2' to

```
'SELECT @v_1:=1, @v_2:=2'
```

or at least make sure you use @ whenever referencing your vars. see this thread for more info:
[SELECT INTO Variable in MySQL DECLARE causes syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error)

Comment: Mhhh, tried it but doesn't work. The problem seems to be more related to prepare/execute/deallocate. If I execute the select into directly it works:   "DECLARE myvar INT;
  DECLARE myvar2 INT;
  SELECT 1,2 into myvar, myvar2;
  SELECT myvar, myvar2;" but when I prepare the sql stmt first it doesn't seem to recognize the variable and it complaints about it not being declared: "  DECLARE myvar INT;
  DECLARE myvar2 INT;
  SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT 1,2 into myvar, myvar2');
  PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE s1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
  SELECT myvar, myvar2;"

Comment: Found the solution now: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?98,186645,186658#msg-186658

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need the dynamic SQL inside your procedure, you can simpler syntax:

```
DECLARE v_1 INT;   DECLARE v_2 INT;   DECLARE v_3 INT;

SELECT 1,2 into v_1, v_2;
SET v_3 = v_1 + v_2;
SELECT v_3;
```

Using normal variables declared inside stored procedure are safer than the user-defined variables (@-variables) as a call to another stored procedure may change your user-defined variable value.

Comment: Thank you slaakso, the thing is that I need the dynamic sql, I need to prepare the query first dynamically due to selecting from different tables and other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify little code to work properly
see my modification

```
DECLARE v_1 INT;
DECLARE v_2 INT;
DECLARE v_3 INT;

SET @sql=CONCAT('SELECT 1,2 into @v1, @v2');
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE s1;

SELECT @v1, @v2 INTO v_1, v_2;
SET v_3 = v_1 + v_2;
SELECT v_3;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE s1;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.
A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.