# Mysql variable value is null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `checkAdminAccess`
(
IN accountID INT
)
BEGIN
DECLARE staffID INT;
#DECLARE num INT;    

SELECT StaffID INTO staffID
  FROM staff 
 WHERE AccountID = accountID
   AND IsAdmin = 1;

SELECT staffID;

IF (staffID IS NULL) THEN
    CALL raise(1356, 'Admin access required.');    
END IF;

END;
```

For any input I get the staffID as NULL. 
For example:

```
call checkAdminAccess(3); #returns null
call checkAdminAccess(6); #returns null
```

And my data is below:

```
INSERT INTO `staff` (`StaffID`,`AccountID`,`RoleID`,`ManagerID`,`IsAdmin`) VALUES (1,3,1,1,0);
INSERT INTO `staff` (`StaffID`,`AccountID`,`RoleID`,`ManagerID`,`IsAdmin`) VALUES (2,6,2,1,1);
```

Can someone tell me how to do select a value into a variable in Mysql?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Select into variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13351479/mysql-select-into-variable)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you check the return value of a procedure, which must be null, since a procedure does not return any value. It maximum returns a resultset.

Possible solutions:

1. Change the procedure to [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html), that returns the staffid.
2. Add an out parameter to the procedure and use that to retrieve the staffid. The above link also describes how to do this.

Comment: The original intention is to throw error than selecting StaffID. `SELECT staffID;` is for debugging purposes only. I want to throw error when staffID is null (not admin). So in this case raise method is called for both scenarios, which is not desired. I have Microsoft SQL Server background where this will work fine. I would like know if there is a equivalent way of select into in Mysql. I am considering function option too. Thanks.

Comment: The select into part works in your code. I do not understand your question.