# My MySQL 'select into' clause is not working like on SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have 'select into' local variables in my MySQL database and it's only working on first variable. I am not sure why it's not working. 'select into' works like in SQL on MySQL?

```
SELECT 
    adresse_a, 
    adresse_b, 
    adresse_c,
    adresse_d_oid

        into    
            @a,
            @b,
            @c,
            @d_oid


    from table where oid = my_oid limit 1;
```

and it's in procedure / loop and always shows
a - good value
b,c,d is empty / null.

Comment: Are you using any tool to execute this query, like workbench?

Comment: yes - MySQL Workbench 6.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current syntax is perfectly fine. See it running in Fiddle at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/25436

Using Mysql Workbench may create problem as reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7338940/

For the Workbench, query could be re-written like this:

```
SELECT 
    @a:=adresse_a, 
    @b:=adresse_b
FROM `table` 
WHERE id = my_oid limit 1;
```

Comment: Yes. It's working now. But I have another problem. As I said query is in procedure / loop. So now my Workbench shows me results (over 1000). It's possible to avoid that?

Comment: @boski sorry, i am not sure about that. Can you find paging of results in the Workbench?

Comment: I deal with it in other way, by adding 'into @...' - then Workbench is not showing me sets of results