# Why does this MySQL if statement on SELECT COUNT(*) not work?

Tags: mysql

I have a `.bat` file which executes the SQL file as follows.

The aim is that if records are found in a table, nothing will be done, whereas if the table is empty, some records will be inserted.

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE rowCount INT; 
  SELECT count(*) FROM `martin1` INTO rowCount;
  IF rowCount <= 5 THEN

  END IF;
END;
```

But when I execute it, there is an error. I tried to delete the `DECLARE`, but even for `(IF SELECT COUNT(*)...>0)` there is still an error.

The error is,

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE rowCount INT' at line 2

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You can use this if construct only in stored programs. The same goes for SELECT ... INTO variable. Have a look at [MySQL Compound-Statement Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html)

Comment: What @VMai said is absolutely correct. You may want to post what you are actually trying to do? there may be an alternative.

Comment: error is "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n ear 'DECLARE rowCount INT' at line 2"

Comment: so is it impossible for a bat file to check select count(*)? thank u

Comment: No it's not but you will have to wrap that code in a stored routine like stored procedure or functions.

Comment: Please explain just what you want to do inside your IF ... END IF. Probably the query could be rewritten with a HAVING clause.

Comment: hi thank u all.what i want to do inside IF END IF is to insert some rows. well so,it is impossible to use a bat file to execute a sql file to realize the function that "control whether there is records in one table, if there is, do nothing, else insert some rows"? th eonly possible way is doing a stored procedure? i am not expert in mysql but i remember for stored procedure in sql server, it may be stored in database ,right? thank u very much again

Comment: anyway for goving value i've done SET @a=(SELECT count(*) FROM `martin1`);and it is right,but still for IF STATEMENT
IF(@a>0)
SELECT "A is greater tahn 0"
END IF  there is an error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this way

```
BEGIN 
  DECLARE rowCount INT; 
  SELECT count(*) INTO rowCount FROM `martin1`
  IF rowCount <= 5 THEN

  END IF;
END;
```

[And have a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error)

Comment: thank u very much for ur kindness reply.but i was told an error with this code "ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
nual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear 'DECLARE rowCount INT' at line 2"