# Looping SQL query in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, workbench

trying to run a query in workbench that will cycle thru all of the site_ids and test my query against each of them. this should be easy but i'm missing something.

```
SET @user_id = 449;
SET @getsites.site_id = 11;
WHILE(@getsites.site_id < 535) DO
     SELECT routine goes here
     SET @getsites.site_id = @getsites.site_id + 1;
END WHILE;
```

Comment: Why can you not just write a simple SQL statement like `select ... from table where user_id = 449 and site_id between 11 and 534`?

Comment: will help me pin down the problem site if the query runs until it bombs, vs. just bombing right away on the whole query, which it does now.

Comment: You can still do that by running `select ... between 11 and 272` and `select ... between 273 and 534`. See which one fails. If first one fails, run `select ... between 11 and 142` and `select ... between 143 and 272` and so on. That's like binary search and you might find the problem in fewer steps than running sequentially looking for failures.

Comment: If you still decide to do what what you are doing, I'd recommend [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx) and [select into](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error)

Comment: the query only accepts one site_id not a range so just wanted to do a simple loop or while

Comment: these example show it should be possible, however none of them work in Workbench https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mysql-stored-procedure/0596100892/ch04s03.html

Comment: May we ask what the actual problem is when the query you want to test "bombs"? It might be easier than you think to tell what's going wrong...

Comment: it is a correlated query that just stopped working after 6 months of heavy use. I'm trying to figure out what set of data is the issue and it'll be tied to a specific site or sites.

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing a proc block, you can convert this with your requirements.

```
DELIMITER $$
USE test$$ -- database name
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_name$$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
BEGIN
DECLARE user_id INT(3) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE site_id INT(4) DEFAULT 0;
SET site_id = 11;
REPEAT
    SELECT 1; -- routine goes here [execute your logic here]
    SET site_id = site_id + 1;
UNTIL site_id < 535 END REPEAT;
SELECT "Proc completed" AS Result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

First you try with SQL, if not possible then try procedure.