# Get base url from CompleteURL using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get base url from CompleteURL using sql.

Example: completeUrl: [SELECT INTO Variable in MySQL DECLARE causes syntax error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075147/select-into-variable-in-mysql-declare-causes-syntax-error). I want get :https://stackoverflow.com/

```
select left(CompleteURL, charindex('/', CompleteURL, charindex('://', CompleteURL ) + 3 )  - 1 )
from urls2;
```

Comment: What database are you using?  The syntax in that answer is neither MySQL nor Oracle.